# ConTeXt: Apply columns to sections without bracketing each section

Tags: sectioning, context, two-column

## Background

Creating a document that can have zero-, two-, or three-column layouts, depending on user preferences. I would like to keep the content clean of `\columnsets` by redefining only the sections (both section and chapter pages have independent styles).

For example, this produces the desired outcome, but requires duplicating the `\startcolumnset` for each `\startsection`, which I'd like to avoid:

```
\definecolumnset[StyleColumns][n=2,
  %rule=on,
]

\startsection[title={Section1},reference=sec:section1,]
  \startcolumnset[StyleColumns]
    \placefigure[left]{}{%
    \externalfigure[7b104cc5c6.jpg][width=\textwidth]}

    This is a sentence that is really, really, really and very long.
  \stopcolumnset
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Section2},reference=sec:section2,]
  \startcolumnset[StyleColumns]
    \placefigure[left]{}{%
    \externalfigure[7b104cc5c6.jpg][width=\textwidth]}

    This is a sentence that is really, really, really and very long.
  \stopcolumnset
\stopsection
```

(The [vertical rules](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Columns#Vertical_lines_between_columnsets_.28rules.29) don't work for me yet, but that's a separate issue.)

## Problem

There are potentially hundreds of sections in the book that gets automatically generated. I would like to define whether or not multiple columns are used outside of the main content in a [single location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) within the document (i.e., before the first `\startbodymatter`).

Forgiving my accent, I would like to do something such as:

```
% <CODE BLOCK>
\let\OldSection\section
\define\section{%
  \startsection
    \startcolumnset[StyleColumns]
      \OldSection
    \stopcolumnset
  \stopsection
% </CODE BLOCK>

\startsection[title={Section1},reference=sec:section1,]
  \placefigure[left]{}{%
  \externalfigure[7b104cc5c6.jpg][width=\textwidth]}
  This is a sentence that is really, really, really and very long.
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Section2},reference=sec:section2,]
  \placefigure[left]{}{%
  \externalfigure[7b104cc5c6.jpg][width=\textwidth]}
  This is a sentence that is really, really, really and very long.
\stopsection
```

That way when the document is generated, if the `<CODE BLOCK>` is not included then the document won't use multiple columns.

## Alternative Approach

I considered using conditional modes, but that would lead to either messy or duplicated content.

## Question

How do you create a document using ConTeXt such that the `\startsection`...`\stopsection` code blocks can be made columnar without actually embedding `\startcolumnset[X]`...`\stopcolumnset` within each section's code block?

## Related

- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Columns
- http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/columns.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `after` and `aftersection` keys to apply the column set for
the given section. The `after` hook is injected between the section head and the content, `aftersection` at the end of the section. If column sets should not be applied to the entire
document, you can define individual heads for the column text. Otherwise just
redefine `section` using `\setuphead[section]`.

```
\definecolumnset
  [StyleColumns]
  [n=2]

\definehead
  [ColumnSection]
  [section]
  [after={\startcolumnset[StyleColumns]},
   aftersection=\stopcolumnset]

\starttext
  \startColumnSection [title=Section 1]
    \dorecurse{4}{\input knuth\par}
  \stopColumnSection

  \startsection [title=Section 2]
    \dorecurse{4}{\input knuth\par}
  \stopsection
\stoptext
```

Comment: Note that `beforesection` is applied before the section heading, so strictly speaking the above is not equivalent to the OP. For that you would need to use `after={\startcolumnset[StyleColumns]}, aftersection=\stopcolumnset`, which, I admit, is a bit weird